# Output content from render_to_string using global variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, erb

I am inside a Controller where I have a method that saves information inside global variables like the following

```
@var = "test"
```

Now when I want to render the view file I am using the following code

```
MyController.new.render_to_string(:template => 'folder/file.erb', :layout => false)
```

The issue I'm having is that inside the **file.erb** it cant access the variable **@var** for some reason. The code goes as follows:

```
<% @var.each do |v| %>

<% end if !@var.nil? %>
```

Which is returning null as it's content. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass it as a local:
`MyController.new.render_to_string(:template => 'folder/file.erb', :layout => false, :locals => { :var => @var )`

Then it will be accessible as a local variable `var` (without `@`).

If you want to do some Rails magic, you should point an action where your `@var` is defined:
`MyController.new.render_to_string(:template => 'folder/file.erb', :layout => false, :action => 'your_action_name')`
so Rails will be able to reuse your variable in the view